# Criar uma ListView com ponta triangular em aplicação JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação JavaFX, e quero fazer um menu a partir de um ListView, que será acionado a partir de um botão pressionado, porém gostaria de colocar uma ponta triangular na parte de cima deste menu conforme a imagem que enviei, porem não consegui via CSS. Como que posso fazer uma ListView parecida com a da imagem??

[image: Modelo de ListView]

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas classes que podem ajudar com isso, elas são `Line, Polygon` e `Canvas`.
  É um pouco complicado mas vai aí um exemplo usando a classe `Line`.

```
/*O construtor da classe Line recebe 4 parâmetros opcionais, 
eles correspondem as coordenadas 'x' e 'y', os dois primeiros onde começa a linha,  
os dois ultimos onde termina a linha.  
Você terá que criar duas linhas, onde uma terminar a outra vai começar.
Supondo que sua ListView tenha uma largura de 400px, para o triângulo ficar
ficar mais ou menos no centro você pode fazer assim:*/

Line line1 = new Line(175, 50, 200, 0);//startX = 175, startY = 50, endX = 200, endY = 0
Line line2 = new Line(200, 0, 225, 50);//startX = 200, startY = 0, endX = 225, endY = 50
// coloque dentro de um HBox
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2);
//centralize as linhas no hbox
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
//depois coloque o hbox e a listview dentro de um VBox
VBox vbox = new VBox();
vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox, listview);
```

Pode não ser a melhor maneira, mas é uma opção.

Sistema de coordenadas: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_coordenadas_cartesiano

Comment: Eu tentei usar o objeto Triangulo e ListView dentro de um Hbox no Scene Builder, mas não consigo redimensionar o triangulo para um tamanho menor, para colocar na parte de cima e no centro do ListView. Vou tentar esse método e retorno para falar se funcionou. :)

Comment: Consegui fazer aqui usando Polygon, vlw pela ajuda!!! :D